# How to get subview with on NSEvent like mouse up on NSView?

Tags: objective-c, drag-and-drop, mouseevent, nsview

I have multiple NSview with multiple subviews respectively within each NSView. I want to perform action on Drag & Drop. I could Drag view. but on Drop I want to get on exact subview dropping is performed. I am trying to get exact subview with NSPoint using hitTest: but it is returning null. Is there any other way to get subview on mouseEvent?

Comment: Did you implement the `NSDraggingDestination` protocol?

Comment: yes!! I have implemented NSDraggingDestination protocol. @Willeke

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Drop location in NSView](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32971540/drop-location-in-nsview)

Comment: Okey.. But How can we get inner subview with NSPoint? @Willeke

Comment: From the documentation of `draggingLocation`: "the current location of the mouse pointer in the base coordinate system of the destination object’s window". From the documentation of `hitTest:`: "A point that is in the coordinate system of the receiver’s superview, not of the receiver itself.". You have to convert the point.

Comment: Yes , Thanks this helped me. @Willeke